# what is Doctrine 2 DQL function equivalent to MySQL function st_within

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, spatial

What is Doctrine 2 DQL function equivalent to MySQL function `st_within`?

I do need this function since I am getting this error below when running this DQL query:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 165: Error: Expected known function, got 'ST_Within'
```

The DQL I am trying to run is:

```
    public function getAdsInBounds($numberPerPage,$page){
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("m")
            ->from($this->getEntityClassName(), "m")
            ->where("ST_Within(point(m.lng, m.lat), envelope(linestring(point(10.090792984008772,36.83717099338201 ), point(10.310519546508772,36.749467295867646 )))")
            ->orderBy("m.date", "DESC");

    return new Paginator($qb->getQuery()->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $numberPerPage)
            ->setMaxResults($numberPerPage));
    }
```

**FYI** the MySQL query works perfectly and returns the expected result.

Thanks,

Comment: Doctrine doesn't support that statement nor any public repository that you can use for that. You need to implement a custom function by yourself : https://github.com/mapado/MysqlDoctrineFunctions this bundle have implemented custom functions of mysql, you could start right there. For the spatial functions There is a bundle for that bug I don't Found the st_within statement : https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial

Comment: thanks @CarlosDelgado I will check them both ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bundle for spatial functions that support MySQL and postgres , the functions can be found here :

[St_within](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial/blob/master/doc/common.md)